# Register component with PerWcfOperation lifestyle (using config file)

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor

How is it possible to register a component in Castle Windsor 3.0 with PerWcfOperation lifestyle? I could only find examples of registering components in code.

Here is my config:

```
<castle>
  <facilities>
    <facility id="wcf"
              type="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfFacility, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration" />
  </facilities>
  <components>
    <component id="Settings"
               service="SomeNamespace.IApplicationSettings, SomeAssembly"
               type="SomeOtherNamespace.ApplicationSettings, SomeOtherAssembly"
               lifestyle="PerWcfOperation" />
  </components>
</castle>
```

When I try to do it as in the config above, I get ConvertException 'Could not convert from 'PerWcfOperation' to Castle.Core.LifestyleType.'

Comment: why are you using XML for that and not code configuration?

Comment: @KrzysztofKoźmic because we're using xml configuration in the rest of our application, so it's imposed. Is XML obsolete in castle now?

Comment: not explicitly, no. It's been de-facto obsolete since 2008, I guess, or since Windsor had proper registration API. Why would you be using XML in 2012? Genuinely curious.

Comment: @KrzysztofKoźmic The reason is that it was the way the components were registered when the development of the application started. So I would prefere not to change it, since there's a lot of code already using this way of registration. Also looking at the Castle Windsor docs I had (probably false) feeling that xml config and registration in code are equivalent.

Comment: But back to the point, is there a way to register it using configuration files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported because XML configuration is considered legacy.

Use configuration in code instead.

XML and code are generally mostly equivalent (where that's possible) although this case is an exception - there's currently no way out of the box to specify scoped lifestyle (and that is what per-wcf-operation lifestyle is) in XML.

Obviously that doesn't mean there's no way to get this working. With a simple `IContributeComponentModelConstruction` you can implement support for that in a few LOC.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about the `IContributeComponentModelConstruction` solution? I do understand that it allows me to augment / change how things are initialized, but will it allow me to have components with lifestyle set to `PerWcfOperation`? Cause I can't change it blindly to `PerWcfOperation` for all the components, only for selected ones.

Comment: @Krzysztof Kozmic - One advantage of using XML configuration is that the root application (that owns the IoC container instance) doesn't need to have references to all components i.e. the dependent component only needs to be in the bin directory at the time of Resolve. Am I missing something, here?